# How are 4D cost volumes constructed for DL based stereo matching?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, papers

I read a paper on Stereo Matching using Pyramid Cost Volumes (paper link: [Semantic Stereo Matching with Pyramid Cost Volumes](https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_ICCV_2019/papers/Wu_Semantic_Stereo_Matching_With_Pyramid_Cost_Volumes_ICCV_2019_paper.pdf)). At some point, in the proposed architecture, after:

1. Feature extraction from both *left* and *right* images
2. Performing adaptive average pooling at three scales (4, 8 and 16)
3. Reducing number of channels using 1x1 convolutions at each scale.

the authors form a *cost volume* by concatenating the corresponding unaries from the *left* and *right* image features and packing them into a 4D volume. The final dimensionality is:

$$C \times \alpha W \times \alpha H \times \alpha D, \alpha \in \{\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{8}, \frac{1}{16}\} $$

, where C - number of channels, W and H - width and height of the images, D - *maximum disparity*.

My question is, for all the possible *disparities*, how can this 4D volume be visualized? How is the volume, for each possible *disparity*, constructed in the first place?